# Spring job fails on step Exception but I don't want it to

Tags: spring-batch

So I have this job.  It has 15 steps.  The steps can be turned on or off as to whether or not they will run (based on the client).

The decider decides `COMPLETED` or `FAILED` based on whether or not the checkbox has been selected for it to run or not.

The problem is that I cannot specify what happens on the  method itself.  In other words, I cannot say on FAIL, go to step 3 within the tasklet.  So if any of my steps tasklets throw exceptions, the wholejob fails.  I would like only the individual step to fail.  Is this possible?

```
<job id="regularEndOfDay" parent="jobParent" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
<decision id="eodStep01Decider" decider="eodDecider01">
   <next on="COMPLETED" to="eodStep01PrintChartOfAccountsReport"/>
   <next on="FAILED" to="eodStep02Decider"/>
</decision>
<step id="eodStep01PrintChartOfAccountsReport" next="eodStep02Decider">
   <tasklet ref="printChartOfAccountsReportTasklet"/>
</step>
<decision id="eodStep02Decider" decider="eodDecider02">
   <next on="COMPLETED" to="eodStep02PrintListOfEmployeeGoals"/>
   <next on="FAILED" to="eodStep03Decider"/>
</decision>
<step id="eodStep02PrintListOfEmployeeGoals" next="eodStep03Decider">
   <tasklet ref="printListOfEmployeeGoalsTasklet"/>
</step>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case I was getting an error when I tried to modify the step like so:

```
<step id="eodStep01PrintChartOfAccountsReport" next="eodStep02Decider">
   <tasklet ref="printChartOfAccountsReportTasklet"/>
   <next on="*" to="eodStep02Decider" />
</step>
```

and I couldn't figure out why.  Upon closer inspection and reflection I realized the

```
next="eodStep02Decider"
```

was what was causing me problems.  Once I removed it then it let me put the `next="on"` in the step and all is well.

Sorry to waste anyone's time on this.  Hopefully someone else in the future finds this and it helps them.